# Inner HTML if statement not recognizing a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, image, innerhtml

I tested the following code in IE, Chrome, and Firefox and it does not work in any of them. I have read several questions about similar problems but they have not offered solutions that fix my example.

I am trying to create a pause/play button that interfaces with JWplayer (I also want it to interface with flowplayer, once I get the button working) and the image will change depending on which image is currently there. I also have a stop button that stops the player completely and changes the image of the pause/play button to pause.

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeimg()
{
  var obj = document.getElementById('image1');
  var imgtag1 = '<img src=\'PLAY.png\'>';
  var imgtag2 = '<img src=\'PAUSE.png\'>';
  if(obj.innerHTML == imgtag2)
  {obj.innerHTML = imgtag1;}
  else
  {obj.innerHTML = imgtag2;}
  return;
}

function playimg()
{
  document.getElementById('image1').innerHTML = '<img src=\'PLAY.png\'>';
  return;
}

</script>

<div id="image1" href="#" onclick="changeimg(); jwplayer('mediaspace1').play(); jwplayer('mediaspace2').play(); jwplayer('mediaspace3').play(); jwplayer('mediaspace4').play();"><img src='PLAY.png'></div>
<div href="#" onclick="playimg(); jwplayer('mediaspace1').stop(); jwplayer('mediaspace2').stop(); jwplayer('mediaspace3').stop(); jwplayer('mediaspace4').stop();"><img src='STOP.png'></div>
```

The play/pause function works, and the first div WILL change into the pause img (so the javascript is going through) and it WILL change back into play if I click on the second div (stop function - triggers playimg() ) but it will not change back into the play image if I click on the pause button again.

For security reasons I can't link the website, but any help would be appreciated

Comment: Browsers can add whitespace sometimes; you might want to try .trim()-ing the html before comparing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you really want to change is the SRC of the IMG tag, not necessarily the entire innerHTML. As machineghost mentions in his comment, there may be whitespace added or other changes to the full HTML that may make your comparison come out as false.

However, you could check if obj.src == "PLAY.png" and set the SRC attribute directly. Something like this:

```
function changeimg()
{
  var obj = document.getElementById('image1');
  var img1 = 'PLAY.png';
  var img2 = 'PAUSE.png';
  if(obj.src == img2)
  {obj.src = img1;}
  else
  {obj.src = img2;}
  return;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to affect obj.src (trying image1 as the id of the img tag instead or the div tag) and it's behaving the exact same way - it changes the play button to the pause button but not back again.

Comment: Found it, I was experimenting and printed the .src and it was returning the entire URL http://mysite.com/site/PLAY.png instead of just pause/play. Thanks for the tip about src!

Answer (score 0):

I think the innerhtml you are replacing in `changeimg()` is affecting the whole obj element, which is a div. So, `if(obj.innerHTML == imgtag2)` will return `false` since the div innerhtml is not imgtag2, but the next time you are going to call `changeimg()`, "obj" will be undefined because you replaced its innerhtml with an HTML code that doesn't have an id: `{obj.innerHTML = imgtag2;}`

Check the console to see if there's any javascript error, which it should, at `if(obj.innerHTML == imgtag2)`

rgds.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether `PLAY` is present or not and then change innerHTML according to it

```
function changeimg()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById('image1');
    var imgtag1 = '<img src=\'PLAY.png\'>';
    var imgtag2 = '<img src=\'PAUSE.png\'>';
    if(obj.innerHTML.indexOf('PLAY') != -1)
    {obj.innerHTML = imgtag2;}
    else
    {obj.innerHTML = imgtag1;}
    return;
}
```